# What is the correct way to use image in place of the H2 tag without affecting the SEO ranking in a bad way?

Tags: seo, wordpress, html, content, title

I'm designing a WordPress post template where I have more than one section on the page each section has a picture as it's main heading.

my question here is what is the best practice to implement this without affecting SEO since I'm replacing the H2 tag with an image?

I'm considering doing one of these solutions

```
<h2><img src="---" alt="the second section title"></h2>
```

or like this

```
<h2 style="display:none">the second section title</h2> 
<img src="---" alt="the second section title">
```

which one is better? and is their any better solution to approach this?

---

## Summary

the first option seems to be better since Alt text does not count as "hidden text" if it accurately describes the image, which is that in my case.

as for the second option it's not suggested since it might violate [google hidden text and links guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en&ref_topic=6001971)  and it's semantically incorrect since it will be considered part of the section content while the image represent the section title.

Comment: Is it a picture with fancy text, a photograph, a drawing, or something else?

Comment: Your first idea, the image is the heading for that section. In your second idea, the text is the heading and the image is just another part of the section. Think about that. Is your image really a heading?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes it's a fancy representation for the title here a [sample](https://imgur.com/3orS7Oh)

Comment: @Rob yes my image shall be placed in place of the heading and it should be considered as the title of the section not part of the section content.

Comment: How about you make the green, image-y elements part of an image that you express as the background of a CSS class called by the H2 and have the letters be regular text enclosed in the H2? That way you get the full "benefit" of using a header with regular text and it still looks fancy?

Comment: @ICap the problem, if I followed this approach, can I be certain that the text will always be in its correct position compared to the background.so I dropped this approach because I feared that the text might overflow out of the image. because of different factors like different screen resolution or the font failed to load for whatever reason which might cuse the text to go out of the image or be out of the place.

Comment: Fair enough, though you can configure for and test with the typical resolutions as well as host the font from redundant sources. I tend to come at web stuff from an SEO perspective so that's why I always push for text as strings versus text as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your image consists of stylized text of your second section title. Basically, that the image *is* the heading, itself.

In that case the first idea is better. Google, at least, is smart to things being hidden by CSS anyways.

And in the second idea, the `img` is not part of the heading itself, which isn't semantically correct.

Comment: so in the first case, Google will detect the image alt text as the H2 tag text ? or it will consider the H2 tag as an empty tag and consider the page without any H2 tag?

Comment: Correct. When Google crawls the page as text, it should read the alt text of the image and interpret it as the H2 text content. You can double check this after Google crawls it by viewing the cached page in Google and clicking "Text-only Version".

Comment: The trouble is that if you try to get too tricky about showing different content to Google than to your users, you might go against Google's [hidden text and links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en&ref_topic=6001971) guideline, which while it probably won't hurt you, probably can't help either.

Comment: I'm setting the alt text to be exactly as the text in the image  .and my main concern of implementing this as what you just mentioned. 
so is it better to just remove the H2 tag and list the image directly to be on the safe side since H2 tag existence doesn't really affect the SEO ranking but help google organize the content. 
or go with the first solution since I'm not hiding anything and the text inside the image is the same as the alt text ?

Comment: Alt text does not count as "hidden text" if it accurately describes the image, which in this case, it does. There's no concern warranted there. I still say go with the first option.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help